# Saving state of a web page for users

Tags: c#, html, sql, asp.net, .net

I am trying to implement a like counter. That on a click of button increases like count by one in the database and then I am changing its text to "unlike" after clicking again my value is decrementing by 1 in the database too. It all works fine untill the page is posted back.
 For eg. If a user clicks like button then text of that button changes to unlike. But if the user reloads the page then. He again gets the button as "like" but not "unlike" is there anyway I can save the state even after postback in asp.net.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well, you have a database, right?

Comment: Yes, I do have a databasy

Comment: " is there anyway I can save the state even after postback in asp.net" You mentioned you saved the data in the database, so just restore the latest data from the database...isn't that why you put it there?

Comment: I am storing like count that is integers in the database I am talking about the button text i.e like and unlike

Comment: @user9209261 so just use the current value from the database to decide the text which gets rendered onto the button. It's a simple if or switch statement

Answer (score 0):

You will need to store the 'like' state in a session variable if you want it available between page switches/reloads.

This might help:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e43755ba-49f1-49b9-aa68-448ecf033a62/how-do-you-store-session-variable-in-c?forum=csharpgeneral

Alternatively, get the 'like' state from the database when generating the page. 
If you're still experiencing issues, your browser might be caching the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on to Javascript, you can try SessionStorage to hold values between page refreshes. It lasts only within the lifetime of a browsers tab and automatically destroyed when the tab/ browser is closed. Values remain completely on the client side and managed by the browser.

[Session Storage (W3Schools)](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_sessionstorage.asp)

Ex (extracted from the above website):

```
// Store
sessionStorage.setItem("lastname", "Smith");
// Retrieve
document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = sessionStorage.getItem("lastname");
```